# Chrom Extension: Close event not available on SidePanel closure

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to clear out my chrome storage which is being managed when the sidepanel opens up.
But there are no click event available for close button of a sidepanel.

```
The close button I'm referring is as below in a sidepanel
```

[image]

There is a port connection way mentioned over [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#type-Port) but I could get it working with my set of requirements.
I need to accomplish this in a `background.js` file

Comment: Using ports is the correct approach and it works in this case. Another solution is to use chrome.storage.session. How/why are you using storage?

Comment: Storage is being used to save TabId and to show the sidebar only if the sidebar is opened by visiting a specific tab and clicking on action button. But overe here once a user clicks the close icon of sidebar the bar closes but since the storage still has the TabId, re visiting the tab opens it again (which shouldn't be the case)

Comment: Well, use ports. What doesn't work? Show the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my working code:

sidebar.js

```
chrome.runtime.connect({ name: 'mySidepanel' });
```

background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
  if (port.name === 'mySidepanel') {
    port.onDisconnect.addListener(async () => {
      console.log('Sidepanel closed.');
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I had no hopes that this would be possible, but this solution works. Thanks!