# Chrome extension - clear all changes on page when side panel closes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on an Google Chrome extension which will allow the users to change page on which they're currently at.
I've decided I want to use Chrome side-panel as my extension menu. I'm using react to create UI of that menu.

So when user clicks some buttons on menu of my extension which is in side-panel, the page they're currently at changes it's styles. I'm doing the changes in DOM of the current page using content script. The buttons in my menu are calling **chrome.tabs.sendMessage** and the content script is receiving these messages using
**chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(messagesFromReactAppListener);**.

I want to remove all my changes on the page when user closes the sidePanel.
Is there some easy way to detect closing sidePanel?
I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77089404/chrom-extension-close-event-not-available-on-sidepanel-closure) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77063723/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-the-chrome-sidepanel-is-open), that's the most recurring answer for that case but unfourtanetly this doesn't work for me.

If I put listener in my content.js and try to connect from my index there is always the same error:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving
> end does not exist.

I've tried connecting to port using setTimeout but the delay doesn't help there

Manifest:

```
{
  "short_name": "Ext",
  "name": "Extension",
  "description": "My test extension",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "action": {
    "default_title": "Show menu"
  },
  "side_panel": {
    "default_path": "index.html"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/icons/icon16.png",
    "48": "images/icons/icon48.png",
    "128": "images/icons/icon128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "sidePanel",
    "tabs"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "*://*/*"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "./static/js/content.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

my content.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
  if (port.name === "mySidepanel") {
    console.log("hello");
    port.onDisconnect.addListener(async () => {
      console.log("Sidepanel closed.");
    });
  }
});
```

My index.ts

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./styles/index.css";
import MainPanel from "./components/MainPanel";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement
);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <MainPanel />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

setTimeout(() => {
  let port;
  while ((port?.name?.length ?? 0) === 0) {
    try {
      port = chrome.runtime.connect({ name: "mySidepanel" });
    } catch {}
  }
}, 1000);
```

So maybe instead of detecting sidePanel closing is there possibility to just "revert" changes?

Comment: Use chrome.tabs.connect (in the side panel) with a tab id and chrome.runtime.onConnect (in the content script), then listen to onDisconnected event as shown in the first solution. This way you won't need polling in setTimeout. P.S. You need to [re-inject content scripts](/q/10994324) after reloading/installing the extension.

Comment: onConnect with tabId worked thanks